# Display, just can't get it figured out

Tags: display

I am having a problem with display hardware. Display works but as soon as I boot to OS windows logo comes up and then as soon as it is going to welcome screen everything goes blank. Any ideas?

Comment: How long are you leaving it at this blank screen before turning off / restarting

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like either:

- your display can't handle the resolution Windows is set to use
- you have a faulty graphics card driver.

I would recommend you boot into safe mode (press <kbd>F8</kbd> after POST and select "Safe mode"). You should be able to get into Windows and set the resolution from there.

Otherwise (if first step doesn't resolve your issue), it's most likely a faulty graphics card driver, which you should resolve by booting into "safe mode with networking" and update the driver from there. You should be able to find an updated driver from the manufacturers (either PC or the GPU) website.